# How exactly do "Domains of Dread" function?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, campaign-settings, ravenloft

So I've never played *Curse of Strahd* or anything in the Ravenloft campaign setting - but I'm working on my own campaign world and I was reading through some texts and found out about Domains of Dread. They definitely sound like a concept I'd want to implement, but I'm not quite sure I understand them.

From what I read, it looks like (in Ravenloft) there are a bunch of different "domains" that are all separate from one another, kind of like countries are separated?

Are Domains of Dread separate from the Prime Material Plane? How does one get there from the aforementioned plane? Is it even possible? If not, is it possible to "summon" the creature who owns the domain into your plane, thus bringing their domain with them?

I know that with worldbuilding, pretty much anything goes, but I just want to have a bit of a baseline to work from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's a collection of [demiplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Demiplanes)

Specifically, the [Domains of Dread](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Demiplane_of_Dread) or Demiplane of Dread are demiplanes controlled by the Dark Powers about whom very little is known, save that they attract evil or despairing creatures like [Strahd von Zarovich](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Strahd_von_Zarovich), who is imprisoned in the Demiplane of Dread known as [Barovia](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Demiplane_of_Dread#Barovia).

> Are Domains of Dread separate from the Prime Material Plane?

Yes.

> How does one get there from the aforementioned plane?

However the DM decides.

[A wardrobe in a creaky mansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe). [Tieing at 'Rock, Paper, Scissors' 100 time in a row](https://regularshow.fandom.com/wiki/First_Day). [Through the looking glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass).  [Over the Rainbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Wizard_of_Oz). [By it materialising on this plane and taking you back when it goes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadoon). [By getting hit on the head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Connecticut_Yankee_in_King_Arthur%27s_Court).

If you try really, really hard it *might* be possible to come up with a way no one else has thought of.

> Is it even possible?

Yes.

> If not, is it possible to "summon" the creature who owns the domain into your plane, thus bringing their domain with them?

Not applicable.

Comment: Ah I see, looks like I misunderstood then - thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I think it would be most useful to not to leave out the one method that is actually used most often in official Ravenloft lore to get characters into the Domains of Dread: magical mists.

Comment: In the middle section, I recommend citing some known cases of how people arrive in Ravenloft: e.g. mists envelope you being the most common one. If there's anything explaining that people can wind up there tons of different ways, that would be worth quoting as well. This helps establish some authoritative basis that one might wind up there nearly any way at all, after which those other unrelated-canon ideas could be provided (via a wardrobe, tieing at rock paper scissors, etc.)